# How do I define a constant in C# and use it in XAML?

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml, converters

I try to define constants for string values whenever necessary to avoid burying "magic strings" in the code. I recently found myself needing to define a custom format string for a converter, so I defined `public const string MyFormat = "a";` in the converter. When using the converter, I need to pass in "a" as the `ConverterParameter`, but rather than typing `ConverterParameter=a`, I would like to refer to the named constant.

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind SomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter=???}" />
```

I've tried `ConverterParameter=local:MyConverter.MyFormat`, but it just passes in the string "local:MyConverter.MyFormat" rather than "a".

I've tried `ConverterParameter={x:Bind local:MyConverter.MyFormat}` but I get an error `Nested x:Bind expressions are not supported.`

I've tried `ConverterParameter={StaticResource MyFormat}` and adding it as a resource, but that just moves the problem and introduces a new problem:

1. I don't know how to reference the constant in the resources either. I can add `<x:String x:Key="MyFormat">a</x:String>`, but then I've defined the constant in two different places and if it changes I have to remember to update it in two different places.
2. Even if I do this, the string is not passed as the parameter as expected. The parameter is null.

Is there any way to refer to a named constant in XAML? *(Note: this is UWP, not WPF.)*

Here's a simple repro:

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="XamlConstantReference.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:XamlConstantReference"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
        <!--  How do I refer to MyConverter.MyFormat rather than defining it a second time?  -->
        <x:String x:Key="MyFormat">a</x:String>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--  How do I refer to MyConverter.MyFormat rather than passing in ConverterParameter=a?  -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{x:Bind SomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter=a}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{x:Bind SomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter=local:MyConverter.MyFormat}" />
        <!-- <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{x:Bind SomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Bind local:MyConverter.MyFormat}}" /> -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="{x:Bind SomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource MyFormat}}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace XamlConstantReference
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _someProperty = "Hello World!";

        public string SomeProperty
        {
            get => _someProperty;
            set
            {
                if (_someProperty != value)
                {
                    _someProperty = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SomeProperty)));
                }
            }
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

MyConverter.cs

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace XamlConstantReference
{
    public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public const string MyFormat = "a";

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if (parameter == null)
            {
                return $"Fail. Formatted '{value}' with null parameter.";
            }
            else if (parameter is string parameterString)
            {
                switch (parameterString)
                {
                    case MyFormat:
                        return $"Success! Formatted '{value}' with parameter '{parameterString}'.";

                    default:
                        return $"Fail. Formatted '{value}' with parameter '{parameterString}'.";
                }
            }

            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the `{x:Static}` markup extension in XAML to reference const members from a C# class. See marked duplicates. If you have trouble, post a new question but make sure that question includes a good [mcve], instead of the above.

Comment: @PeterDuniho {x:Static} does not exist in UWP. I reviewed all of the questions you linked to before I posted my question. All three are WPF and do not apply to UWP. I specifically stated in my question, "(Note: this is UWP, not WPF.)" And I clearly provided a repro with my question that I created specifically for this question.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I didn't notice the UWP-specific nature. That said, you should read [mcve] so that you understand what an actual [mcve] really is. The code above most certainly is not. I've updated the duplicate link to the Q&A that directly addresses your question, i.e. by explaining that lacking the x:Static markup you will need to expose the values as bindable members. (My error notwithstanding, do not add tags to the title on Stack Overflow posts.)

Comment: @PeterDuniho Again, I read both of those questions before posting my question, and I posted my question because neither one answered it. The first one deals with enums and provides solutions for using an enum value in XAML, but does not address how to use a string constant and cannot be extended to a string constant. The second one addresses static strings, which are similar but not identical to constants, and suggests that there is no way to bind to a static variable in UWP. The answer to my question may well be "It's not possible," but it is not a duplicate of either question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Regarding the repro, I did scan through the link you posted before replying. It clearly states "Complete / Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included in the question itself: If the problem requires ... include code for both. If ... include code for all three. The problem might not be in the code that you think it is in. Use individual code blocks for each file..." I provided the minimal amount of code to build a working project and reproduce the issue. What specifically do you recommend be left out?

Comment: _"The first one deals with enums and provides solutions for using an enum value in XAML, but does not address how to use a string constant and cannot be extended to a string constant."_ -- sure it does. You should get in the habit of reading past the first answer to a question. _"suggests that there is no way to bind to a static variable in UWP"_ -- sounds like an answer to your exact question to me. The type of data you want to use doesn't seem relevant here.

Comment: _"What specifically do you recommend be left out?"_ -- whatever is not actually needed. I'm not going to waste time going through your post line by line, but for example, there's no need for error-handling code for this example, nor all of the XAML markup you've got (one single property binding is sufficient for the task at hand). There is a _lot_ of code in your post that simply does not matter here.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The point here is that you closed my question as a duplicate when it is *not* a duplicate. I read all of the questions you linked before posting my question, and they do not answer my question. You may disagree, but since I'm the one with the question and I wasn't able to find any answer in any of the existing questions, after reading them in their entirety, I think it's fair to say that I'm in the better position to judge whether it is a duplicate.

Comment: @JeremiahMercier Just a note that that last argument (I'm the one asking so I know whether it's a duplicate) is quite fallacious. Typically the issue is that an asker simply *doesn't know enough to understand how* a question is a duplicate. I'm not saying that is the case here; I just want to point out that such a line of reasoning is a dangerous one that should not be relied upon.

Comment: @TylerH As a general case, you make a fair point. In this case, PeterDuniho and I strongly disagree as to whether it is a duplicate question and we have both reviewed the same material. In this case, he has explained what he believes are the similarities while I have explained why they are different. Since I'm the one that has the question and none of those similarities were sufficient to resolve my question, I seem to be in the better position to conclude that it is therefore not a duplicate.

Comment: @TylerH Regardless which of us is "correct", my objection is that the question was arbitrarily closed as a duplicate because a single user believed it was a duplicate, without offering me even a brief opportunity to provide an explanation. I believe a more appropriate response would be to flag the question as a possible duplicate and allow other users to vote to confirm that it is a duplicate or allow me an opportunity to clarify before closing the question.

Comment: @JeremiahMercier The system affords gold tag-badge holders the ability to unilaterally close a question tagged with said tag, on account of they have been weighed a "subject matter expert" by the community; specifically, at least 1000 times, across at least 200 (non-wiki) answers, people have found their answers in that tag helpful. This is by design and typically works quite well. Also by design, you as the question asker can make an edit to your question at that point explaining how it is not a duplicate, and the question will enter the Reopen Review Queue, where community members will [...]

Comment: @JeremiahMercier [...] decide whether it is worth reopening. However, you need to do that explaining in an edit, not just in the comments. If three users agree to reopen the question, it will get reopened. If that fails, or if you don't want to wait, you can do as you did and ask for input from Meta, where a broader group of SMEs will typically see your plight. That's the road you took and it resulted in your question being reopened.

Comment: @JeremiahMercier With regard to flagging the question, users with 3,000 reputation or more *cannot* flag a question as a possible duplicate; they can only vote it as such (3 votes from such users or 1 vote from a subject matter expert or 1 vote from a moderator will close a question). Furuther, users who have a gold tag badge *cannot* choose to apply a 'normal' close vote; a duplicate close vote from a gold tag badge user *will* result in a unilateral closure. This is enforced by the system due to the extra weight afforded the close vote cast by the SME.

Comment: @TylerH Thank you for the explanation. This is helpful to know.

Comment: This comment thread is awful to read if you came here looking for answers.
Have we decided that it's just not possible in UWP (because `x:Static` does not exist), and that there is no possible way to reference a constant in C# code from XAML?